# Diseñar un folio especifico desde DDL en un base de datos

Tags: mysql, sql

Me acaba de surgir una curiosidad. Me gustaría realizar una tabla donde pueda definir un campo llamado como  "folio" compuesto por fecha de realización y un numero incrementable a lado de la fecha. Este folio será una `PRIMARY KEY`. Algo como esto: Una persona hace una compra y obtiene un folio `1811011-> AAMMDDN`. Quiero que el gestor me la haga en automático y no que lo tenga que tenga que programar en un lenguaje de programación para agregarlo o insertarlo. 
¿Cómo creen que podría hacerlo?

Comment: si lo vas a tener que programar, tu requerimiento es muy especifico

Comment: ¿No podría haber la posibilidad que lo pudiera establecer en el campo desde en el gestor? Ya que por ejemplo cuando definimos un campo fecha nosotros podriamos establecerlo que se agregue en automatico colocando 
     `campo_fecha  DATETIME DEFAULT NOW()`. Creí que se podría definir algo similar en un campo como lo ya mencionado en titulo.

Comment: la respuesta que te dieron es a lo que me referia, hay que generar todo el procedimiento

Comment: Sí, gracias. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consulta rara pero me dieron ganas de hacerla y se me ocurrio algo asi:
Creas una tabla donde se van a ir generando la info para armar el ID :

```
        CREATE TABLE idRaro (
                id int not null auto_increment, 
                fecha DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
                primary key(id)
        );
```

Esta seria la tabla original de ejemplo:

```
        CREATE TABLE idRaroTabla(
            folio nvarchar(100) not null,
            dato nvarchar(100) not null,
            primary key(folio)
        );
```

Ya programando tendrias que seguir la siguiente logica:
Al momento de mandar a insertar un registro primero tendrias que hacer esto para que se cree el valor del id con la fecha:

```
  insert into idRaro (valor) values (0);
```

Y despues vas a tu tabla original e insertar tu dato y en id obtenes ese dato que se cargo en la tabla anterior y lo concatenas:

```
  INSERT into idRaroTabla(folio, dato) values ((SELECT concat(id, ' - ', fecha) from idRaro order by id desc limit 1), 'Venta');

  SELECT * FROM idRaroTabla;
```

Cuando haces el select mi ejemplo devuelve esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De ahi en adelante cada vez que insertes un dato tenes que programar que haga el mismo proceso, primero que inserte el id y fecha y dsp insertando tus datos en la tabla original poniendo como id la concatenacion del id y la fecha que generaste en la otra tabla:

```
  insert into idRaro (valor) values (0);

  INSERT into idRaroTabla(folio, dato) values ((SELECT concat(id, ' - ', fecha) from idRaro order by id desc limit 1), 'Otra venta');

  SELECT * FROM idRaroTabla;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta respuesta fue mejor de la que yo esperaba. Gracias.